# how to add installed compiler path in qt creator

Tags: linux, qt, gcc

I installed a cross compiler (G++) in my debian linux system to work on QT creator.  It's for Debian version 6.0 with ARM processor.

After installing I selected *Tools->Option->Build&Run->Compilers-->Add*.  It is showing a list of options like **LinuxIcc**, **MinGW**, **GCC**, **Clang**, **Custom** and **QCC**

What option should I select?

Comment: `G++` is `C++` compiler variant of `GCC`. select `GCC`

Comment: @ramtheconqueror : Ok, Thank you for that information. Now the problem is i added the G++ compiler manually but it is showing in kit option while i create new project, Am i missing any procedure while add new compiler

Comment: @ramtheconqueror :do you have any link for how to add compiler manually

Comment: it is showing or not showing in kit options?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror : i corrected the compiler settings , now it is showing in kit option.